# Facebook like profile page in asp mvc - architecture issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Users on my site have their profile page. There, users can setup their data. On edit button press this page become editable.

Now another user can explore other users profiles.

So I wonder here:

1. Should I make two controllers `ProfileController/Index` and `ProfileAsAnotherUserSeeItController/Index`. First use profile owner to setup data and another use other users to see those data?
2. Have just one controller `ProfileController/Index` and based on some parameters decide what data to display (edit buttons, remove profile page items buttons etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would have a single controller => `AccountsController` or `UsersController`. In that I would have an `ActionMethod` called `Details` which lists all the details for a particular user.

If my site was StackOverflow, a sample route would be: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/30674/pure-krome`

which translates to

`{controller}/details/{id}/{optional anything .. which in this case is a name, for SEO}`

I would also have an `Edit` action method

eg
`http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/30674`

or

`{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Now, the logic in the `Details` Action Method would determine what is to be displayed on the view. So, if you want to have an Edit button, the controller action method should figure this out and the view will only display it, if it's been told to.

eg (pseduo code)

```
public ActionResult Details(int userId)
{
    var user = Database.Load<User>(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var viewModel = new DetailsViewModel
                    {
                        DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                        Name = (user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName).Trim()
                    };
    if (LoggedInUser != null && LoggedInUser.HasRole(Roles.CanEditThisUser)
    {
        viewModel.IsEditButtonVisible = true;
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and the view will be simple.. like

```
<snip html stuff>
@if (model.IsEditButtonVisible)
{
    // display edit button Html code.
}

// Display user details Html stuff..
```

Things to note :-

1. Views are strongly typed to their own ViewModel.
2. The Controller does all the *figuring* out of things.
3. View is really really dumb.

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes the most sense to have two actions which serve different views of the profile page. Whether or not you implement these actions in two separate controllers isn't important.

If you place all the logic in a single view to determine which content to display based on the context your view, is likely to become more difficult to maintain compared to having two completely separate 'display' and 'edit' views.